# How do I disable the composable preview in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have several composables with a preview in my activity. they take a long time to render, and I only need to check one composable. How do I disable the composable preview in Android Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the `group` attribute in the Preview.

Something like:

```
@Composable
@Preview(group="Test")
fun test1(){ }
```

Then in the Preview panel you can select the preview group:

[image]

In this way you can select the preview to be displayed.